# cellForRowAtIndexPath NSRangeException

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
Application Specific Information:
```

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -'[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'`

```
0   CoreFoundation                  __exceptionPreprocess + 124    
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 objc_exception_throw + 56    
2   CoreFoundation                  -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:] + 0    
3   UIKit                           -[UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 252   
4   someApp                         -[businessViewClass methodA:] (businessViewClass.m:298)   
5   someApp                          -[businessViewClass scrollViewDidScroll:] (businessViewClass.m:292)    
6   UIKit                           -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _notifyDidScroll] + 76    
7   UIKit                           -[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 460    
8   UIKit                           -[UITableView setContentOffset:] + 300    
9   UIKit                           -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary] + 60    
10  UIKit                           -[UIScrollView setContentSize:] + 128    
11  UIKit                           -[UITableView _applyContentSizeDeltaForEstimatedHeightAdjustments:] + 56    
12  UIKit                           -[UITableViewRowData setHeight:forRowAtIndexPath:] + 572    
13  UIKit                           __53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 3016    
14  UIKit                           +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 80    
15  UIKit                           -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 460    
16  UIKit                           -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 788    
17  UIKit                           -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 80    
18  UIKit                           -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2360    
19  UIKit                           -[UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 136    
20  someApp                            -[businessViewClass methodA:] (businessViewClass.m:298)    
21  UIKit                           -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _notifyDidScroll] + 76    
22  UIKit                           -[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 460   
23  UIKit                           -[UITableView setContentOffset:] + 300    
24  UIKit                           -[UIScrollView _smoothScrollWithUpdateTime:] + 2400    
25  QuartzCore                      CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 40    
26  QuartzCore                      CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 424    
27  IOKit                           0x000000018334de54 0x183348000 + 24148    
28  CoreFoundation                  __CFMachPortPerform + 180    
29  CoreFoundation                  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56    
30  CoreFoundation                  __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 436    
31  CoreFoundation                  __CFRunLoopRun + 1800    
32  CoreFoundation                  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384    
33  GraphicsServices                GSEventRunModal + 180    
34  UIKit                           UIApplicationMain + 204    
35  someApp                            main (main.m:15)    
36  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000182b528b8 0x182b50000 + 10424
```

This is what happend.

I find an bug that exists in app online, but I can't reproduce it with project code. It seems a business method was called when scroll the `UIScrollview`, and this business method call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of `UITableView`, and then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` trigs the `scrollViewDidScroll` method of `UIScrollView`. And I call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in `scrollViewDiddScroll` method. It comes back. but It doesn't recurrence because next method called is `NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex` instead of trigging the `ScrollViewDidScroll` method of `UIScrollView`. and then `NSRangeException` occurred.

is there anybody meet this or any ideas? thank you.

Comment: Show the code in `cellForRow`

Comment: You need to show the code; particularly the line where the crash occurred.

Comment: looks like your array is having 3 objects but you are trying to access 5th index object.

Comment: You have 3 elements in your array and you are trying to access the 5th object.

Comment: Share your tried code than someone might help you.

Comment: Do not call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` manually.

Comment: @TejasK You can call `cellForRow(at:)` on the tableview.  You shouldn't call the delegate method manually.

Comment: @Paulw11 : That's what I said Paul :)

Comment: It isn't clear from your comment - there are two `cellForRow` methods. The one that is being called in the stack trace is the one on the tableview - this can be called.  The delegate method should not be called, but it isn't in this case

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, you're right , I don't call the delegate method. I call the cellForRow of UITableView

Comment: I don't call the delegate method. I call the cellForRow of UITableView

Comment: and the crash happend int UIKit , not my business code. It crashed out of my control

Comment: Just encountered this problem as well and have no idea about it. Seems that U have to catch the `NSRangeException` manually to avoid crashing the app.

Answer (score 1):

Your numberOfRowsInSection method of tableview is returns value that is greater than your array of count.

array's count is 3 and you are accessing 5th object of array.

Comment: I don't call the delegate method. I call the cellForRow of UITableView

Comment: How you are defining the number of rows in your table view?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is put a check to avoid any such crash, just look at this example code. This will be helpful just in case you aren't able to reproduce it.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.yourArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (self.yourArray.count > indexPath.row)
    {
        // your code for the cell
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I don't call the delegate method. I call the cellForRow of UITableView

Comment: So you can put the check I put above in the cellForRow of UITableView.

Comment: I mean - (nullable __kindof UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

Comment: not
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

Answer (score 0):

Your counting through an array but you are counting too far, thus not in bounds. You need to count the exact amount of units in the array.

Use this:
[_array count];

Comment: I don't call the delegate method. I call the cellForRow of UITableView

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.yourArray.count;
}

Comment: I mean - (nullable __kindof UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
not - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath